# Grid of images overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of images. and when one is clicked an overlay of reduced opacity should be displayed over the top, if another is clicked then the previous one should go back to normal and the new one have the overlay. I have tried loads of different ways and nothing works:

```
<div class="grid-item">
  <a href="overlayActiveOne()">
    <img src="img/img.png" class="img-responsive">
  </a>
  <div id="overlay-one"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <a href="overlayActiveTwo()">
    <img src="img/img2.png" class="img-responsive">
  </a>
  <div id="overlay-two"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <a href="overlayActiveThree()">
    <img src="img/img3.png" class="img-responsive">
  </a>
  <div id="overlay-three"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <a href="overlayActiveFour()">
    <img src="img/img4.png" class="img-responsive">
  </a>
  <div id="overlay-four()"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay-one #overlay-two #overlay-three #overlay-four {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
function overlayActiveOne() {
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay-one")
    overlay.style.opacity = 0.7;
}

function overlayActiveTwo() {
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay-two");
    overlay.style.opacity = 0.7;    
}

function overlayActiveThree() {
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay-three");
    overlay.style.opacity = 0.7;    
}

function overlayActiveFour() {
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay-four");
    overlay.style.opacity = 0.7;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```js
$('.grid-item').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.grid-item').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item img{ 
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;  
}

.grid-item.active .overlay{
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <div class="overlay">Overlay</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <div class="overlay">Overlay</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <div class="overlay">Overlay</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just add/remove the `active` class to/from the parent...then it's just CSS. No need to go searching up/down the DOM.

Comment: But opacity is changing on overlay when parent is clicked.

Comment: Like this I mean - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rxyLwx. Jquery is less complex and only requires changing the CSS slightly.

Comment: That is very smart, i never thought of that. One question, should i first remove class from others then add class to $(this) or is order of that important at all.

Comment: One thing. The small images act as controls for a carousel and the carousel images is the one which is changing at the moment not the small ones

Comment: It works either way..the order would be up to the OP

Comment: @fdsfdf That's why you should explain what you are doing more precisely. This sounds like you need to ask **another, separate** question to fully explain what you want. Do NOT edit this question as it will invalidate the answer given.

Comment: I wasn't going to edit this question! I've made a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617782/grid-of-images-carousel-controls-overlay